# Can't see root level non-ee php files

Tags: php, structure, htaccess

Weird one - haven't seen this before. Just launched a newly upgraded from ee1 to ee2 site at www.bankofmarin.com. Everything works fine. This is a Structure site and I have strict URLs on to enforce 404 with bad URLs. Works fine.

We need to place some non-ee php files in the root, and they just aren't working. This one https://www.bankofmarin.com/t.php should show the date. Instead I get the 404 page.

Here is my htaccess:

```
# Enable Rewrite Engine
# ------------------------------
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Use Dynamic robots.txt file
# ------------------------------
RewriteRule robots\.txt /robots.php [L]


# Force the www - this version will not force www on subdomains, only http://bankofmarin.com
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bankofmarin.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


# Force https - this will only force https on the www site
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^staging\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.bankofmarin.com/$1 [R=301,L]


# Redirect index.php Requests
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/admin/.*
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]


# Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I thought it might be something in there but its all pretty straightforward. Any ideas?

Comment: Was this solved for you? or do you still need assistance?

Comment: Nope still can't make it work. Haven't had time to look at it again in a few days though.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not an .htaccess guru, but we worked with someone to develop a base .htaccess file for use with our clients, and they all contain this

```
## MOD REWRITE BASE
## Checks for file/folder before serving pages in ExpressionEngine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.org/$1 [R]
## END MOD REWRITE
```

The goal was to always have EE check to see if there was a file that existed first, then process ExpressionEngine requests and it's been working for us. We just modify the {domain} component for each client.

If I recall, the consultant who helped us with this said that

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

checks for the file name first, then

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

checks for a directory with said, file, then

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

removes the index.php. The remainder is the domain magic.

We've been using that as a base for .htaccess file for over 6-8 years now, it it hasn't failed us.

Comment: Excellent response. The `!-f` should get Chad squared away.

Comment: That code is already in my htaccess.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize I could scroll down. This could be an order issue. Did you try moving the EE piece before the index.php Redirects?  What you can do is comment out the full # Redirect index.php Requests section, then check to see if the file loads. If so, then move the Standard EE ReWrites up higher and remove the comments. If it stops working again, then you probably have a conflict between the purpose of the two statements.